# $.remove() is removing events from detached element?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

The element is being appended to list items when mouse is over them, and detached when mouse is out.

When the element is clicked, it gets detached, and then the list item to which it was part of is removed from the DOM.

My HTML:

```
<div id="cart">
    <ul>
        <li> <a data-item="a">item A</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="b">item B</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="c">item C</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="d">item D</a></li>            
        <li> <a data-item="e">item E</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="f">item F</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="g">item G</a></li>
        <li> <a data-item="h">item H</a></li>         
    </ul>    

</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
  function plugin(node, opts){
    var self = this;
        delKnob = $('<i />').text('×');

    this.cart = $(node);

    delKnob
      .on('click', function(){              
        var item = $(this).parent().find('[data-item]').data('item');
        $(this).detach();
        self.remove(item);
      });

    this.cart
      .on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
        delKnob.appendTo(this);
      })
      .on('mouseleave', 'li', function(){
        delKnob.detach();
      });
  }

  plugin.prototype = {
    remove: function(item){
      var li = this.cart.find('[data-item="' + item + '"]').closest('li');
      li.addClass('removing');
      setTimeout(function(){
        li.remove();   
      }, 500);    
    }
  };

new plugin('#cart');
```

I've set up a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/C4kZw/) that resembles my code.

The problem is that the click listener from this element also gets removed with the list item, even though the element is being detached before `$.remove()` fires, so it shouldn't be affected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @bfavaretto If they're delegated, that means they belong to the container...which is the `#cart`, not the `li`s

Comment: @Ian I realized just after posting, but wasn't fast enough to delete that comment...

Comment: @bfavaretto And I realized **that** after my comment was submitted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in what you believe is going on, except that when you detach the `delKnob`, your mouse immediately enters the `li` which contained it, meaning it gets re-attached, so when the `li` is removed, `delKnob` is still a child and as such gets removed as well.

I tested this by adding a `console.log()` to the code:

```
this.cart.on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
    console.log("delKnob attached!");
    delKnob.appendTo(this);
})
```

Fix this by removing the `delKnob` in the `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    li.find('.delKnob').detach();
    li.remove();
}, 500);
```

This assumes adding the class `delKnob` to the element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AHjRN/

As a side note, I would simplify the whole thing and just add a `delKnob` to every `li`.  Then you just show/hide them, and don't have to worry about removing the handler.  It also simplifies the code quite a bit:

```
function plugin(node, opts) {
      this.cart = $(node);

      this.cart.find('li').append($('<i class="delKnob"/>').text('×').hide());

      this.cart.on('click', '.delKnob', function () {
          var li =  $(this).closest('li').addClass('removing');
          setTimeout(function () {
             li.remove();
          }, 500);
      });

      this.cart.on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
          $(this).find('.delKnob').show();
      })
          .on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
          $(this).find('.delKnob').hide();
      });   
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F3Qdp/

Comment: Looks like you're right, and it can be fixed by detaching the delKnob right before removing the li (from within the setTimeout callback). See http://jsfiddle.net/C4kZw/6/

Comment: Interesting. If it gets `.remove()`d, how can it be re-appended to the DOM though? I thought that's only possible with `.detach()`. Maybe I need to read that stuff again

Comment: @Ian, I am not sure, but it probably has something to do with appending something from the `delKnob` variable that was initialized in `plugin`.  It is a jQuery object, but the handler is in the DOM, so it acts a little weird.

Comment: Yeah, this was it. I've added a temporary variable to check the state: http://jsfiddle.net/C4kZw/8/

Comment: @OneTrickPony: I think you can simplify your code quite a bit by just putting a delete button on every `li`.  It means a lot less stuff to worry about.  I would also use a single delegated handler for the entire cart, instead of adding one to each `delKnob`, as my new example above.

Comment: In that case, the mouse over events are not required either, because the button can have `display:block` on `li:hover .delKnob`. Yes, it's probably a better idea, thanks :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony: Yes, you are correct... That simplifies it even more:  http://jsfiddle.net/F3Qdp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding an event to the `delKnob` which is (re)moved around, you could use event delegation and bind an event to the container (`this.cart`) that handles any `.delKnob` descendant being clicked.

```
delKnob = $('<i class="delKnob" />').text('×');      

this.cart
  .on('click', '.delKnob', function(){              
    var item = $(this).parent().find('[data-item]').data('item');
    $(this).detach();
    self.remove(item);
  });
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/nxsgV/)

Comment: Thanks! This also seems to fix the issue